# Is it possible to persist a table lock even when the connection is lost?

Tags: mysql

How can I keep a table locked even when the connection is reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think thats possible, as MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/lock-tables.html) says:

> If the connection for a client session terminates, whether normally or abnormally, the server implicitly releases all table locks held by the session (transactional and nontransactional). If the client reconnects, the locks will no longer be in effect. In addition, if the client had an active transaction, the server rolls back the transaction upon disconnect, and if reconnect occurs, the new session begins with autocommit enabled.